# I'm implementing on-the-fly dashboards in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

Can I implement something like:

```
    $scope.showDashboard = function () {
        $scope.dashboardPath = "/Widgets/Weather/View.htm";
        $scope.widgetController = 30;

        require(['/Widgets/Weather/Controller.js'], function (w) {               
            whatShouldIputHere = w;
        });


    };


 <div ng-include src="dashboardPath" ng-controller="whatShouldIputHere?"></div>
```

Is it possible to assign a controller to ng-include dynamically?

There could be many widgets on the dashboard

Answer (score 4):

There is a project in development that implements dashboard functionality with AngularJS.

Features:

- Adding/removing widgets
- Widgets drag and drop
- Any directive can be a widget

Running Demo http://nickholub.github.io/angular-dashboard-app

Demo source code https://github.com/nickholub/angular-dashboard-app

Dashboard directive itself https://github.com/nickholub/angular-ui-dashboard

Answer (score 2):

We created an angularjs based dashboard in the open source [hawtio](http://hawt.io/) project. You can noodle the code here if you like:

https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/tree/master/hawtio-web/src/main/webapp/app/dashboard

For each widget on the dashboard we compile the partial directly with a child scope
https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/blob/master/hawtio-web/src/main/webapp/app/dashboard/js/dashboard.ts#L142

Though we had to patch angularjs to allow us to use custom injection on child scopes. e.g. so that we can use a different implementation of $location for each child widget (so it thinks its on its own real URL etc). Hopefully when custom injectors are supported we can move to that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using dynamic controllers why not use a single controller(the one which has the showDashboard method). **Adding dynamic controller with `ng-include` will result in nested controllers** which is illegal i guess. And instead of using ng-include as an attribute use it as an element.

```
<ng-include src="dashboardPath"></ng-include>
```